# What is the use of applying img_to_array() after cv2.imread()

Tags: keras, image-preprocessing, opencv

In a book, I saw the following code to load images from a directory:

```
1.image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
2.image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
3.image = cv2.resize(image, (28,28))            
4.image = img_to_array(image)
5.data.append(image)
```

**cv2.imread()**

> It converts image to a numpys array in BGR format

**img_to_array()**

> It converts *PIL* instance to numpy array, but in this case image will stay in BGR format as the image is loaded by *cv2*.

What is the use of **img_to_array()** *(from keras.preprocessing.image module)* after **cv2.imread()**, as it is already in numpy array.

### Also:

To double check, I displayed images before and after applying *img_to_array()* using **cv2.imshow()**.

#### BEFORE applying img_to_array()

[image]

#### AFTER applying img_to_array()###

[image]

### Also Also:

But, if I try to save the images using **cv2.imwrite** into a file, they both are saved as normal (ie. like the first image). Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the data type you provide to the imshow() function.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563):

> The function may scale the image, depending on its depth:
> If the image is 8-bit unsigned, it is displayed as is. If the image is
> 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. That
> is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to [0,255]. If the image is
> 32-bit or 64-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by
> 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

So when you use cv2.imread() it reads data *uint8*, that is 8-bit unsigned format thus imshow() displays the original data.

But when you use img_to_array() it converts data to the float. Thus imshow() multiplies it with 256. It expects the float values in normalized form, that is all the pixels are divided by 256. That is the reason for such a display.

This is how cv2.imread() data looks like...
[image]

and its data type...
[image]

This is how img_to_array() data looks like...
[image]

and its data type...
[image]

If you divide your image by 1.0 to convert it to the float...

```
import cv2
# from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
image = cv2.imread("car.jpg")
image = image/1.0
cv2.imshow("Divided by 1.0", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

...this is what you will get:

[image]

Same as img_to_array.

But it you divide image with 256.0 as follows:

```
import cv2
# from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
image = cv2.imread("car.jpg")
image = image/256.0
cv2.imshow("Divided by 256.0", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You get the original image since imshow() multiplies the float with 256.

[image]

So what you need is to divide your img_to_array() output by 256 or convert it to the *uint8*.

Comment: Thanks @Shahriyar, So,  img_to_array() is needed to make the array compatible with Keras or I can skip it ?

Comment: Depends on how you use that, mostly yes if the next question you use requires that format as an input. Not otherwise. Try to recheck your outputs after each step.